# Alphabetize web albums

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I find that I have a number of albums with different titles but with the same pictures. It is difficult to organize 3000 albums when they are all over. I would like to alphabetize them so I can organize them better. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about Picasa Web Albums and not Google Photos? The former has been mostly deprecated. Have you tried organizing your albums with Picasa (the downloadable software)?

Comment: Yes, I like the way Picasa web shows the pictures. Google photos shows pictures too big and again I am not able to alphabetize albums; in addition they multiply. Their search ok but not great. Picasa (I changed from Macosx to Mac mini because of pictures) does not have all my photos and I do not want to download from Picasa Web to Picasa all the duplicates. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the [list of albums](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos), there's a sort menu on the right side near the top. If offers three options:

- Album date
- Upload date
- Album title

[image: screen shot showing sort menu]

Choosing "Album title" appears to do what you're asking.